# SQL Server views and stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I am creating a web app using SQL Server on a private framework. This web app has an `orderLines` table that should only show the `ordersLines` of the specific order that is currently opened.

My framework allows to pass views as data objects to tables. So basically I can pass a orderlines view to my table and it shows all the orderlines that are in the db, but the problem is I need only the `orderlines` of my specific order. I have created a stored procedure that receives `orderID` as a parameter, but I don't know how to use it instead of a view.

The stored procedure code is below and the view is pretty much the same just without the checking of `orderID`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[astp_Sales_OrdersLinesProductsByID] 
    (@OrderId INT)
AS
    SELECT        
        ol.OrderID, ol.Created, ol.CreatedBy, ol.Updated, ol.UpdatedBy, 
        ol.CUT, ol.CDL, ol.Domain, ol.ProductID, ol.Amount, 
        p.ProductName, p.Supplier, p.Quantity AS TotalQuantity, p.Price, 
        ol.PrimKey
    FROM            
        dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines AS ol 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.atbl_Sales_Products AS p ON ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
    WHERE 
        ol.OrderID = @OrderId
```

I was thinking that maybe there is a way to add the stored procedure to my view? Because from what I see it's not possible to pass parameters to a view.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: You can't parametrise a `VIEW`, no. A `VIEW` is simply a virtual table defined my a `SELECT` statement. If you need to parametrise a statement referencing a `VIEW` you do you when you reference said `VIEW`: `SELECT {YourColumns) FROM dbo.YourView WHERE YourColumn = @Param;` What have you tried so far to reference the view? You haven't tagged any languages here either, so we don't know what you're working with.

Comment: If you need a parameterised view then look at inline table valued functions

Comment: Seems you confuse things by using terminology loosely and in an undefined manner. "View" means something specific in tsql. But your framework (using an undefined dev environment - c#? MVC?) also uses the term. Don't equate them. And the phrase "pass a view ... to a table" is only meaningful to you.

Comment: And one more thing for clarity. You cannot **define** a view with parameters. But you query a view using parameters EXACTLY in the same manner as you would any other statement executed by your code / framework. This leads back to the prior comment. I think you are confused about your framework and the functionality it offers vs. how to use tsql to achieve the desired result.

Comment: `I am creating a web app using SQL Server on a private framework.` What kind of framework you are using ? [`EntityFramework`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure can be called by using EXEC:

```
EXEC <sp_NameHere> @Parameter = <ParameterValueHere>
```

In your case:

```
EXEC [dbo].[astp_Sales_OrdersLinesProductsByID] @OrderId = 1
```

You cannot SELECT from a stored procedure like you would SELECT from a view or table.

However, I completely agree with SMor (as in: the term "View" means something completely different in SQL). You should reconsider your solution as I assume that the framework you are using will provide a method for building the query and/or filtering the results in a more efficient way.